# Elements disappear on webserver

Tags: html, css, image, class, styles

I have a HTML file that i get from the web, when i open it locally everything looks great, but if u upload the file to web server half of the elements disappear from the page. Even more, some navigators seems to be able to show the elements while others cannot. IE for example shows everything, while Chrome and Opera does not. Here is the code:

```
<div class="top-ads row">
<div class="col-md-4 sec-heading">Top Ads</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a class="left-arr-btn right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev" >
    <img class="left-arr-img" src="images/left-arrow.png">
    </a>

    <a class="right-arr-btn right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <img class="right-arr-img" src="images/right-arrow.png">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

It seems that all top-ads is buggy, here is the styling:

```
.top-ads{
margin-top: 2em;
}
```

I don't understand, if it shows ok from disk, why it shows blank on the web?
I'll try to add some screenshots...
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h98Y.jpg)
[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v40ql.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the images even load? I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the CSS... (actually it might have something to do with the CSS considering how the non-image elements are hidden too)

Comment: Yes, half of them load, and other half does not, you can see it on the screenshots

Comment: You can find the page here: http://all4truck.com/done/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you provided all your code? If so you have no doctype declaration, no html or body tags - modern browsers will forgive this but older ones won't. Read up on html structure here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

This for HTML4:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <P>Hello world!
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And to run html5 instead use this doctype:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: No, it is not all of my code, of course i have doctype, html, and body tags. You need more code? P.S. I use latest Chrome

Comment: Hard to diagnose your issue if you don't provide all details.

Comment: Code is messy and long, you can see it on all4truck.com/done

Comment: The second slider has no html for slides so it will never show anything. You need to add in the html with images so they will show.

Comment: I see in source: "./images/t1.jpg". That's incorrect, you should use two dots, ../images/t1.jpg if that's where this image resides.

Comment: I don't understand, the code is not written by me, can you be more specific? I should mention that when I double click html file it shows everything ok...

Comment: The browser is throwing out the html for the image because it's called incorrectly. See my previous comment for the correct html format.

Comment: I'n not a programmer, so code looks ok to me. It's just i cannot understand why IE shows it while Chrome does not :(

Comment: I've validated your source code and it's awful, with dozens of errors. What you need to do is go here https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and validate your source code and fix all the bugs, then the page should work in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should check your `images` folder is at the right place on the server.

You could also try giving a relative path, by replacing this:

```
src="images/left-arrow.png"
```

by this:

```
src="../../images/left-arrow.png"
```

or an equivalent relative path going back up to the root directory of your website.

Comment: Also a great idea. Do you have an "images" directory on the site that's not showing the images?

Comment: I assume my images are there because half of the images are loading, actually, IE can load even all of them... :(

Comment: Is it something in the image format? (Unlikely but who knows)